# How to add a variable as a tag base?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I need to add a tag base with the country name to filter content based on that variable.

Something like:

http://base_url/country/page_name or http://base_url/country/post_type/post_name

The content would be filtered by a taxonomy using the country variable.

Comment: Do you mean `country` is a taxonomy term? So it could be `http://base_url/belgium/[page_name]` and `http://base_url/france/[page_name]`?

Comment: That's exactly what i need to figure out

Answer (score 1):

I don't say this often but in this case: It is impossible without:

1. hard coding the tags and adding dedicated rewrite rules for those or
2. getting the current tag list on each request and updating the rewrite rules (very slow).

In short: No, forget it.